# Android Phonegap Plugin not working for all version of android device

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, callback

I developed an Android PhoneGap Plugin for getting public album list and upload it to picasa. The plugin is successfully working with the emulator and device. The success callback isnot calling for all android device. On testing on emulator it work for all version and on device with version 2.3.6 it working fine. When testing on android vesion 2.2 and 4.0 the success callback and failure callback isnot call but the product upload on picasa.

Does anybody have any idea as to what could be wrong when the callback are not getting invoked? My Android apps min sdk version of 8.

Thanks in advance